# Is there any API function to get the battery level in Windows Desktop Apps?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a desktop app where I want to get the battery level of my device (laptop). I am using C# for this. Is there any method which would help me do this? I've done this on the Windows Phone 8 platform using the `Windows.Phone.Devices.Power.Battery.GetDefault().RemainingChargePercent`. Is there any similar API on the desktop side too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static string GetBatteryLevel()
{
    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Battery");
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
        using (ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get())
        {
            using (var enumerator = results.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                    return string.Empty;

                return string.Format("{1} {0}%", enumerator.Current["EstimatedChargeRemaining"],
                                     enumerator.Current["BatteryStatus"].ToString() == "1"
                                         ? string.Empty
                                         : "Charging:");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `Windows Management Instrumentation`

Comment: I tried to create the same using the Windows Forms Application. However, my Visual Studio shows errors when I try to use the `Systems.Data.Objects` namespace. What project template did you choose in Visual Studio?

Comment: @TheRookierLearner You can use any project template you like so long as you reference the `System.Management` assembly. 

From the Solution Explorer right click your project and click `Add Reference` and then search for `System.Management` (http://i.imgur.com/CD43hdi.png). 

Once you've added your reference add a using directive to the class `using System.Management;`

Comment: @TheRookierLearner That's a using directive. Before the using directive will work you need to add a reference to the `System.Management` assembly. Not really sure how else to put it.

Comment: Thanks! ^The above comment was helpful. :)